# Laravel: Getting last id on custom PostgreSQL schema

Tags: laravel, postgresql

When requesting the last id on a public schema table with the following command, I'm getting the expected value, but it doesn't work with custom schema:

```
>>> DB::select("SELECT last_value FROM public.users_id_seq WHERE is_called;")
=> [
     {#3703
       +"last_value": 4,
     },
   ]
>>> DB::select("SELECT last_value FROM foo.users_id_seq WHERE is_called;")
=> []
```

These two raw commands give the expected value when executed directly in PostgreSQL.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, a schema is a namespace that contains named database objects such as tables, views, indexes, data types, functions, stored procedures and operators.
A database can contain one or multiple schemas and each schema belongs to only one database. Two schemas can have different objects that share the same name. Therefore, I think that your problem may be one of the following:

- object `users_id_seq` does not in `foo` schema.
- You have not permission to this schema `foo` or to this object `users_id_seq`
- You have not `select` permission on this schema or on this object